# Cannot Parse Form Data in NextJS project - Promise cannot be resolved

Tags: node.js, next.js, formidable

I am trying to parse Form Data via Formidable package in my NextJS v13 project. Here is the code for it:

Client side:

```
// lib/courses.js 
import { mainApi } from '.';

export const coursesApi = mainApi.injectEndpoints({
  reducerPath: 'coursesApi',
  tagTypes: ['Courses'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCourses: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: 'courses',
        method: 'GET'
      }),
      providesTags: ['Courses'],
    }),
    getCourseById: builder.query({
      query: ({ id }) => `courses/${id}`,
      providesTags: ['Courses'],
    }),
    createCourse: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ data }) => ({
        url: `courses`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Courses'],
    }),
    updateCourse: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ courseId, data }) => ({
        url: `courses/${courseId}`,
        method: 'PUT',
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Courses'],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetCoursesQuery,
  useGetCourseByIdQuery,
  useUpdateCourseMutation,
  useCreateCourseMutation,
} = coursesApi;
```

Component where the form is being filled and request to the server is sent:

```
// create-course-component
...
const response = await createCourse({ data: formData })
...
```

Back-End code:

```
...
    console.log('Request: ', req)
    const data: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const form = new IncomingForm();
      console.log('Before form parse')
      form.parse(req, (err: any, fields: any, files: any) => {
        console.log('Inside form parse')
        if (err) reject({ err });
        resolve({ err, fields, files });
      });
      console.log('After form parse')
    });
    console.log('Outside promise')
...
```

It seems that it is STUCK within the Promise. Here is what I get in the console:
[image]

As you can see, Form Data inside the request body looks PERFECTLY fine, but for some reaon the promise is not resolved and it goes into an endless loop I guess.

Any idea why this is happening?